# Upload failed You should use both http and https as schemes for your web intent-filters

Tags: android, intentfilter, android-instant-apps

Upload failed

You should use both http and https as schemes for your web intent-filters.

I am getting this error while uploading the instant app to Play Store. I have declared intent filters for both http and https in Manifest as below.

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:scheme="http"
                    android:host="XXXX" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="XXXX" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Could you please let me know what could be wrong and why i am getting this error while uploading to Play Store ?

Answer (score 7):

Try to declare `IntentFilter` like this

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
    <data android:host="yourhost.ru" />
    <data android:pathPattern="/featurePath" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: I have the same problem of unable to upload instant app, after change the IntentFilter like described then I can upload it successfully, but unfortunately I am having other problem : can not rollout the instant app, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44772959/android-instant-app-is-uploaded-but-can-not-be-roll-out

Comment: I am also facing the same problem while upload the app bundle (.aab) into play store. I have declared the intent filter like you mentioned, but it didn't resolve that issue. What else might be the reason for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Don't change your intent filter code by your own in the Manifest file.

Just go to Tools > App Links Assistants and follow the steps from 1 to 4.

In step 1 itself android studio will automatically add those intent filter codes to your manifest file.

(Source : [Developer Documentation > Add Android App Links](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing.html) )

Follow the steps from the link.

Comment: Not true, because the editor even ask you to add either http or https, it won't add both for one link.

Answer (score 1):

you have to define both in the same intent filter

```
   <intent-filter>  
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="XXXX"
            android:scheme="http" />

        <data
            android:scheme="https"
            android:host="XXXX" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:scheme="http"
                android:host="XYZ"
                android:pathPattern="/app" />

            <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="XYZ"
                android:pathPattern="/app" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="default-url"
            android:value="https://XYZ/app" />
    </activity>
```

Had the same problem. The above manifest solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Agrees with the previous answer, but also add  android:autoVerify="true"  into intent-filter

Answer (score 0):

I did everything mentioned above but finally get rid of this error after adding these permissions in my base module's manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two potential reasons for this issue

**#1** You need to check your `manifiest.xml` and Add both `http` and `https` schemes

*e.g:*

```
   <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:host="www.example.co" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
```

*or*

```
      <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="www.example.com"
                android:scheme="https" />
            <data
                android:host="www.example.com"
                android:scheme="http" />
       </intent-filter>
```

**#2** If you're using deeplinks in your navigation graph you need to include both `http` and `https` as well

*e.g:*

```
    <deepLink
        app:action="android.intent.action.MY_ACTION"
        app:mimeType="type/subtype"
        app:uri="https://www.example.com/example" />

    <deepLink
        app:action="android.intent.action.MY_ACTION"
        app:mimeType="type/subtype"
        app:uri="http://www.example.co/example" />
```