# Android Instant App is uploaded but can not be roll out

Tags: android, android-instant-apps, rollout

UPDATE: 20170703
Using Android Studio 3.0 Canary 5
Modified some AndroidManifest and build.gradle files,

Moved  from inside  to inside  for both Base's AndroidManifest and App's AndroidManifest, like below:

```
<application ...>
    <meta-data android:name="asset_statements" android:resource="@string/asset_statements" />
    <activity ...>
</application>
```

resource asset_statements:

```
<string name="asset_statements">[{\n  \"relation\": [\"delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls\"],\n  \"target\": {\n    \"namespace\": \"web\",\n    \"site\": \"https://example.com\",\n  }\n}]</string>
```

The web verification is passed successfully (see screenshot below), uploaded new APK and ZIP (Instant App) but still same problem of can't rollout the Instant App.

Contacted google playstore support through "live chat", promised will get back but still no response after a few days.

[image]

------ OLD POST BELOW -------
I am using Android Studio 3.0 Canary 4 (preview).

Both Installable APK and Instant App (zip) are already uploaded successfully.

The Installable APK is already rolled out.

### The Digital Assets Link json file already uploaded and verified in https://example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json

I have only 1 Base module (feature module), inside the Base's AndroidManifest have only 1 activity:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.test.app.base.activity.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="locale|layoutDirection|orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="default-url"
                android:value="https://example.com/instantapp/.*" />

            <meta-data
                android:name="asset_statements"
                android:resource="@string/asset_statements" />

            <intent-filter android:order="1" android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:host="example.com" />
                <data android:pathPattern="/instantapp/.*"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
</application>
```

My assets_statements define in /res/string.xml :

```
<string name="asset_statements" translatable="false">
        [{
            \"include\": \"https://example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json\"
        }]
</string>
```

### So currently I believed every thing should be working fine because any configuration problem will be filtered when upload in Google Playstore, currently I can not rollout my Instant App because error :

Errors
Resolve these errors before starting the rollout of this release.

Your site 'mysite.com' has not been linked through the Digital Assets Link protocol to your app. Please link your site through the Digital Assets Link protocol to your app.

Warnings

### Check these warnings before starting the rollout of this release.

[image]

NOTE: example.com is only to replace my real domain.

Please help me to understand what is wrong and how to solve it ?

Comment: I forgot to mention, I am ignoring the Android Studio 3.0 error in "App Link Assistance" -> "Associate Website" -> (1) Adding asset statements failed. (2) Failed to link strings to AndroidManifest.xml (3) Failed to add autoVerify to intent-filter elements (4) Success! Your app is associated with the selected domain(s).

Comment: Can you also check your assets with https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator?
One more thing, see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/44768067/8320998

Comment: Stuck with this same error for more than a week now. did anybody got this resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using [Google Play App Signing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423) then your local keystore contains the Upload Key, which is different than the App Signing Key.

In that case, the SHA256 fingerprint obtained with keytool is not the one you should include the Digital Assets Link json file.

The correct SHA256 fingerprint can be obtained in the Google Play Console, under Release Management / App Signing / App signing certificate.

[Play Console Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePq6Y.png)

Comment: thank for this new insight, I will try it again later after I got the chance to come back to this project (currently doing other)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use path pattern in your deep link:
Make sure you are using your actual domain instead of example.com

```
https://example.com/instantapp
```

Comment: Yes I did use the actual domain name, the https://example.com is just to hide my real domain.

Comment: are you using path: instantapp in link?

Comment: are you asking about my web link "https://example.com/instantapp/" ? yes it is defined in my manifest and in local device everything working as expected, but I can not click the "START ROLLOUT TO PRODUCTION" button in Playstore because the button is disable with that error (see screenshot) .. if you are asking something else please describe more