# get an error when I update an app on Google play console

Tags: android

I'm trying to update an application I have in Google play but I got this error, I don't know what the error is, I don't know what causes it.
The error is:

***The domain name 'CHANGE-ME' you have specified is invalid. Specify a valid domain name.
You should use both http and https as schemes for your web intent-filters***.

I don't use any https inside my application, please help me

Comment: Check the manifest files of each of your modules in your project. There is an intent filter defined somewhere which has `CHANGE-ME` as it's url. If you can't find it, make a full text search (CTRL + F) for `CHANGE-ME`.

Comment: My mainfest did have any CHANGE-ME

Comment: Just want to add more info since i'm facing this issue, anybody can refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44621165/upload-failed-you-should-use-both-http-and-https-as-schemes-for-your-web-intent) and make sure instant app or app bundle properly setup